# Bounds / BoundingVolume of a Model with source "#cube" in QML

Tags: model, qml, cube, bounds, bounding-volume

I need the bounds or the boundingVolume of my Cube-Model in QML.

```js
Model {
            id: test
            source: "#Cube"
            scale: Qt.vector3d(1.2,1.2,1.2)
            position: Qt.vector3d(1, 1, 1)
            Component.onCompleted: {
                   // I want to get the bounds here
                }
        }
```

I've tested a lot. But when I try to get my bounds, they are always undefined or the bounds-Vector is empty.
It makes no difference if I use "Component.onCompleted" or if I check the bounds outside of my model. They are always undefined.

Why do I need the bounds?
I want to put some other Cubes into a big "outerCube" via a Repeater. I have to know where the outerCube-Lines start and end, so that i can make sure, that all innerCubes are inside the outerCube.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that works for me. You get the minimum and maximum vector of the model via bounds.minimum and bounds.maximum and can calculate everything else.